# Redis cluster: will hgetall search all nodes in cluster for key?

Tags: node.js, redis, redis-cluster

Aws elasticache creates a redis cluster by default.

Im using nodejs and using ioredis.

My question is if i call hgetall will it automatically query all nodes in the cluster?
Or is there something else i need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I think what I said here is incorrect, see the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50949026/241294). For a command like `HGETALL` the client library knows where to send it.

From the docs, emphasis mine:

> Every command will be sent to exactly one node. **For commands containing keys, (e.g. ... HGETALL), ioredis sends them to the node that [sic] serving the keys**, and for other commands not containing keys, (e.g. INFO, KEYS and FLUSHDB), ioredis sends them to a random node.

---

No, not automatically. You would need to send `hgetall` to each node in the cluster yourself. There is a `nodes()` utility function returns the array of nodes to facilitate this.

The documentation answers this explicitly and provides an example, see https://github.com/luin/ioredis#running-commands-to-multiple-nodes.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to query all nodes. Use [Redis.Cluster](https://github.com/luin/ioredis#cluster) to connect to the cluster, and it will send the command to the right node.

A decent client library for Redis Cluster should implement the [MOVED and ASK Redirection](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#moved-redirection). The end user of the client library should NOT worry about where the key is located.